# $.ajax().fail()

Tags: jquery

I like to know what kind of reasons can fail the $.ajax() request? I haven't had any chance to see any, because my code's worked perfectly so far, but I really need to know them. Let me tell you why!
Assume the $.ajax request fails for a reason. jQuery gives me this chance to do something in that case by .fail() .Can I try to repeat/resend the request inside the .fail() ? The reason which failed the request, will it occur again? If it does, then will it occur each time I resend the request and crush the application/code?

Comment: Why do you think it would fail? Common reasons for me would be.  Not having permission to the WebService/Controller, the web service is down, not connected to the internet etc.

Comment: Server can goes down or temporal network problem, anything. Just notify user about error and leave it up to him, unless you really know what to do with error.

Comment: It would Probably due to Server Load, Non avaiability of rquested link or sometime (script error) browser bug etc.